# list elements in line using bootstrap for responsive app

Tags: html

I have a nav bar with a list. The items in the list have to be in line on any device.
In my code, the items of the list are in line only for large resolutions, but for mobile they are one underneath the other.
How can I make the in line?
I am using md bootstrap to make this responsive.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <ul>
          <li> my profile </li>
          <li> home </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: `<ul class="d-md-flex"> ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <ul class="d-md-flex">
          <li> my profile </li>
          <li> home </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like so, using bootstrap built in classes for creating columns:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <ul class="row">
      <li class="col-md-3"> my profile </li>
      <li class="col-md-3"> home </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```